# Active Directory LDS Exception

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, asp.net-membership, adldap

Hey stack! I just installed a AD LDS instance in my development machine. The config is the following:

```
<membership defaultProvider="ActiveDirectoryProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ActiveDirectoryProvider" 
             connectionStringName="ActiveDirectoryConnection" 
             connectionUsername="CN=adldsadmin,CN=Users,CN=TestNet,DC=contoso,DC=com" 
             connectionPassword="123456" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider,System.Web,Version=4.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
             connectionProtection="None"
             enableSearchMethods="true"
             applicationName="App1" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

How ever I get the following exception:

> The specified directory service
>   attribute or value does not exist.

The adldsadmin user is in all of the groups. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I found what the problem was. Apparently something to do with authentication. The solution is:

1. Open the command prompt in administrator mode.
2. Type `cd %windir%`
3. Type `dsmgmt` and press enter.
4. Type the following commands pressing enter after each line:

   ```
   ds behavior
     connections
       connect to server localhost:389
       quit
     allow passwd op on unsecured connection
     quit
   ```

   quit

Now it should work.